# SQL Backup location

Tags: sql-server

Can somebody please let me know how I can output a list of the exact path and file name of each and every database that was backed up the last night.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in the SQL Server Logs (assuming you are talking about using SQL native Backup).

A question like this makes me want to ask "Why do you not know which DBs are being backed up and when?"

Comment: Thanks for yout help. Do you have any script to do that?

Comment: @user387268: assuming you have sufficient permissions, you can view the SQL Server Logs through SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 0):

To view the log files in SSMS click the server name to expand the server tree. Then expand Management folder and expand SQL Server Logs. Double click it to see server logs.